# solving a limit as n goes for infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

i have been stuck with this for more than an hour , i tried to divide with the dominant number , but it doesn't worked , any ideas?
i tried to divide by $(-6)^{n}$ and $3^{n}$ but didn't worked

Comment: While not a proof, did you graph in Desmos? For a analytic approach,  you need to break up the exponents in the denominator and then expand

Comment: @imranfat i did break up the exponents didn't reached for any useful thing tho

Comment: Can you share your work with us? And did you make a graph in Desmos?

Comment: @imranfat in Desmos i don't get any graph ... and what i did is not much helpful  i just tried to break the exponents in the denominator and that is it

Comment: Your approach is a good one ... try dividing the top by $(-6)^n$ and dividing the two factors on the bottom by $(-2)^n$ and $3^n$ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard method of taking out highest powers:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{(-6)^n + 3^n}{((-2)^{n+1}-3)(3^{n-3}+2^n)}
& = & \underbrace{\frac{6^n}{2^{n+1}\cdot 3^{n-3}}}_{= \frac{3^3\cdot 6^n}{2\cdot 6^n}=\frac{27}{2}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^n + \frac{1}{2^n}}{((-1)^{n+1}-\frac{3}{2^{n+1}})(1+2^3\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-3})}}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n+1}}=-1} \\
& \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & -\frac{27}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}